# Is componentWillUnmount When There is setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple React web application where a date and time is displayed, and the time is updated every millisecond with the setState function and setInterval function. The code is below:

```
import React from "react";
import TitleBar from "./TitleBar";

class Time extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: "",
      time: ""
    }
    this.updateTime = this.updateTime.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateTime, 1);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  updateTime() {
    let dateObject = new Date();
    let date = dateObject.toDateString();
    let hour = dateObject.getHours().toString();
    let minute = dateObject.getMinutes().toString();
    let second = dateObject.getSeconds().toString();
    let millisecond = dateObject.getMilliseconds().toString();
    let time = hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second + " : " + millisecond;
    this.setState({
      date: date,
      time: time
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TitleBar/>
        <div className="time-div">
          <p className="date-txt" value={this.state.date}> {this.state.date} </p>
          <p className="time-txt" value={this.state.time}> {this.state.time} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Time;
```

My question is, why do I need a componentWillUnmount function when the setInterval function re-renders a new time every millisecond? When I remove the componentWillUnmount function, the application works perfectly as intended, so I don't understand why I should unmount the component or "remove" the setInterval function. Is this just a convention?

Comment: `this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateTime, 1);` looks incorrect. It should be `this.interval = setInterval(this.updateTime, 1);` (no arrow function) or `this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateTime(), 1);` (calling the method, but since you use `bind` in the constructor, I'd use the former, no need for the arrow function).

Comment: Note: Updating your component every millisecond isn't best practice. It will update your component and do unnecessary work quite a lot, because in general the DOM is only repainted 60 times/second (16.66667ms between updates), though it can be faster with some display systems. If you really want to update as quickly as possible, it may be better to use a ref, `requestAnimationFrame`, and direct DOM update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why do I need a componentWillUnmount function when the setInterval function re-renders a new time every millisecond?

So that when your component is unmounted (removed from the page entirely), the interval timer is stopped and the callback stops getting called.

> When I remove the componentWillUnmount function, the application works perfectly as intended,

No, it will try to set state on an unmounted component, which is an error.  (Though you may not *see* much in terms of effects of the error except that over time your page may get slower as more and more endless intervals get scheduled and repeated. If you're using the development version of the React libs in development, they'll give you an error in the console when you try to set state on an unmounted component.)

Here's your component with that line commented out with an error message when it tries to set state after being unmounted:

```js
class Time extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: "",
            time: ""
        }
        this.updateTime = this.updateTime.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.updateTime, 1);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Removed to cause error: clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    updateTime() {
        let dateObject = new Date();
        let date = dateObject.toDateString();
        let hour = dateObject.getHours().toString();
        let minute = dateObject.getMinutes().toString();
        let second = dateObject.getSeconds().toString();
        let millisecond = dateObject.getMilliseconds().toString();
        let time = hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second + " : " + millisecond;
        this.setState({
            date: date,
            time: time
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/*Omitted for example <TitleBar />*/}
                <div className="time-div">
                    <p className="date-txt" value={this.state.date}> {this.state.date} </p>
                    <p className="time-txt" value={this.state.time}> {this.state.time} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showTime: true
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({showTime: false});
        }, 200);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.showTime && <Time />}</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but does the component get unmounted every time it sets a new state? Also, I don't really see any visible error in terms of the time that is displayed, so is there a way that I can know that this is still an error?

Comment: "does the component get unmounted every time it sets a new state" — no. It gets unmounted when it gets removed.

Comment: @pdsla112 - Components aren't unmounted every time there's a render, no. They're mounted, rendered and rerendered as necessary, and then unmounted if they're removed from the page. You may not see an error with the production React libs, but the development ones will log an error to the browser console if you try to set the state on an unmounted component.

Comment: @pdsla112: If you are just rendering time `Time` as the "root", then you won't see any effect since the only time the root unmounts is when the page is closed or reloaded. But components are supposed to be self contained and eventually `Time` might be rendered as a child of another component, etc.

Comment: @pdsla112: UnMounting means completely removing our component from the DOM TREE. Say only when the count value is less than 5, you want to show some your component.  So you will write something like {count<5 && <ComponentName/>} and you will say have a Button on which you are clicking and couter is getting increased. As soon as the count becomes 5, Your Component will be UnMounted from the DOM. Hope this example helps :)

Answer (score 1):

All the `SideEffects` like your events which may be there (In your case `setInterval` and `Timer` associated to it is stopped)
can be Cleaned Up in `componentWillUnMount()` just before the Component gets removed from the DOM Tree.

So, **ComponentWillUnMount()** is for all the `CleanUp stuff`, so that we avoid `Memory Leaks` and improve performance of our Product.

**Part B:**

> When I remove the componentWillUnmount function, the application works
> perfectly as intended.

That doesn't happen actually, you may not experience it in small app. To cross verify open Developer Window and In the events section check whether the Timer functionality is still being fired or not.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you keep setInterval after unmounting the component it will continue to run as an excess load for the browser and it can make your web application slower.